# rails 3 link_to with nested content_tag to create <a href with nested span - how to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, href, link-to, content-tag

Hi I got a noob question, I want to create the following HTML result:

```
<a href="/controller/action" class="button-big layer">TEXT<span class="arrow-big"></span></a>
```

In the above HTML I want to have text with a span-class to style in an image via css.

When I try the following implementations the result reflects just one part of the needed implementation:

```
<%= link_to "TEXT", controller_path, :class => "button-big layer" %>
```

results in:

```
<a href="/controller/action" class="button-big layer">TEXT</a>
```

and

```
<%= link_to(content_tag(:span, "", :class => "arrow-big"), controller_path, :class => "button-big layer") %>
```

results in:

```
<a href="/controller/action" class="button-big layer"><span class="arrow-big"></span></a>
```

Does anyone know how to accomplish?

Answer (score 30):

You could also nest tags by using alternative syntax for link_to helper

```
<%= link_to controller_path, :class=> "button-big layer" do %>
  Text
  <%= content_tag(:span, "", :class => "arrow_big" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your solution, works as well as the other one with a litte "gap". The css style for the "image" which is inserted by the span-tag has to be adjusted because a break is inserted. But that no big thing, well done!

Comment: It's amazing how no one seems to talk about the block option of `link_to` and `content_tag`. It's as if no one needs to nest, or no one uses haml, where nesting content is very cumbersome. Great answer, good to know this is possible with `link_to`, as well as `content_tag`

Comment: been looking for this one for yonks.  Had not comprehended from documentation that link_to could run a block option

Answer (score 10):

Simply concatenate your text with the 'span':

```
<%= link_to(("TEXT" + content_tag(:span, "", :class => "arrow-big")).html_safe,
             controller_path,
             :class => "button-big layer") %>
```

You'll need the .html_safe around the concatenation since the + operator will otherwise escape the HTML of the content_tag.

Comment: Hi, yes well done, this was exactly what I'm searching for. Works as expected without any changes in the css, thanks for your solution :-)

Comment: This worked great, I reversed the text and content_tag for my needs, but it was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Reading your question I did solve my problem.
Than I propose another way to answer your question.

You could create a helper method to make this kind of link that you need.
It would be something like this

```
def link_with_text_and_span(href, text, span_options= {}, link_options = {})
    span_tag = content_tag(:span, span_options[:content] || '', :class => span_options[:class] || '')
    link_to(span_tag, href, :class => link_options[:class] || '')
  end
```

The good about it is that your view will be cleaner.
Then you can just call this helper method in your view

```
  <%= link_with_text_and_span("/controller/action", "TEXT", {class: 'arrow-big'}, class: button-big) %>
```

PS: This code can be improved for sure, if other users want to, please do it.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way you could use without the content_tag. Not the cleanest but it works!

```
<%= link_to '<span class="arrow_big"></span>'.html_safe, controller_path, class: "button-big layer" %>
```